# MC Connector -Sync Lead and Contact Object using Email as Subscriberkey

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Is there any way to define our own Subscriberkey when syncing SF lead and contact object into MC? By default, MC takes the ID field of an object and uses it as Subscriberkey. So let's say I want to define email as ContactID/Subscriberkey in both objects? Is it possible?

OR

When I am syncing Lead and Contact object it automatically takes ID field as Subscriber Key. But when Lead becomes Contact then I have two Subscribers/Contact IDs with same email address in MC, one with Lead ID which is no more exist in lead object and new Contact ID.
Any idea about how to keep the same Lead ID as subscriber key when it becomes a contact?

Comment: MCC always uses ID

Comment: Does that mean noway around to fix this...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is immutable, expected behavior done by the MC Connect Managed Package. And before you do anything else: Email is a terrible, terrible Subscriberkey, please do NOT put any efforts into making it yours.

Why?
People share email addresses.
People change email addresses. (google "natural" vs "surrogate" keys). Email address is Personally Identifiable Information (PII) and as Subscriberkey, it will be in  ALL your data views, Journey Logfiles, Einstein DEs,.... making a lot more places in and potentially connected to your system sensitive (in a GDPR sense) than necessary.

With that said:

If you use the standard Salesforce MC Connect  feature, the Contact / Lead ID (or also User ID) will become your (billable) Contact Record in SFMC / Subscriberkey - either when synching data extensions, or when injecting them into journeys.
This is a pretty unfortunate fact but it poses a rather common challenge. It has been addressed by Salesforce in the following article. If I personally should use one key sentence to sum it up, it would be:

> Learn the advantages of using the Contact object instead of the lead object.

I agree that in connected setups, really the only sustainable solution is to go for SF Contact ID (003xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).
Whether that is possible under your circumstances depends on the usecase a lot, but in order to understand the approach and to get the peace of mind that this is an officially acknowledged challenge, this is absolutely worth your time:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=icx_b2c_crosscloudengagement_modeling_considerations.htm&type=5

If you want to or have to keep using leads AND contacts, then the challenge you need to address is a "mixed model" with two IDs. It's pretty dauting considering you could have running journeys during which people could convert, and you would have to surgically remove and reinsert them, among other things. It can get rather ugly, but going down that rabbithole also kind of derails this question, so I'll stop here. Hope this helped!

Comment: Stepping in a bit late into that topic. But Marketing Cloud Account Engagement (Pardot) handles this well. A prospect is synced with a Lead and once the Lead is converted into a Contact, the prospect syncs with the Contact.

Comment: Apparently Hubspot does so, too, as I have learned. even then it's pretty safe to assume that many other "third" systems will have a harder time dealing with multiple changing person IDs as opposed to one stable one. e.g. bring interaction studio into the mix and you will see the same issue repeated. Not all systems are able to seamlessly mirror conversion, and unfortunately marketing cloud is among those who can't.

Comment: What about introducing a "Sync to MC" boolean on Contact Records on the SFDC side (checkbox on the Object) and Syncing Contacts from SFDC to MC (MC Connect) only if this field is true. While creating Leads from MC, this field will be set to False, and upon Conversion in SF, thanks to Conversion Mapping, the contact's field will have the same value, and hence not be recreated in MC. On the opposite, native SFDC Contacts will.

Comment: Another workaround, to avoid Contact dups in MC, is to delete Leads once Converted in Contacts. For this a Boolean could be set with a SF Flow upon Conversion, and its presence would trigger a deletion in MC.

Comment: The problem with these sorts of solutions is that you have given the old ID out already. So even after conversion, the Lead ID is "publicized" / all over the place for as long as you still have e.g. links in emails, Leads somewhere in journeys, etc. You will keep collecting performance data or unsubscriptions to the old ID, which you'll have to either ignore ensure to "migrate" onto a matching contact. Deleting leads also obviously stops all running workflows & unassociates that lead's performance data unless you take active countermeasures. So on its own this is a pretty blunt measure.

Comment: Sure thing, these are just workarounds, no real solutions. That being said, IMHO, Leads and Contacts should be both used, as Sales Process are built on them most of the time.